# Need a webbrowser component which allows custom download manager to be plugged in

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, download-manager

I need suggestions on possible webbrowser components/controls which allows developers to plug in custom download managers.

Suggestions can include browsers for WinForm.

*P.S.: I have been using [csExWebBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx) for a year or so, but recently I've been facing [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973705/custom-webbrowser-control-fails-to-download-files) with this control.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if it will meet your needs, however take a look the [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) Browser Framework; it is based on the Chromium browser and does indeed look awesome. I was considering using it myself earlier this week however for an internal project.

You will probably have to implement the download manager plug-in system yourself, however using this framework you will be able to incept the navigation requests (i.e. links) and handle them.

Comment: +1 for this answer, you can handle download requests via the [WebView.Download event](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_2/sharp_api/html/365f92a1-3739-40b6-31c6-9c3d8658a1af.htm). See the TabbedWPFSample for a full example (it creates a save file dialog and displays a progress icon).

Comment: Heard a lot about Awesomium when I was looking for a WPF web browser. Well, is there any other browser component that you wanna suggest?

Comment: @Trainee4Life: As far as I know, there aren't any other browser components that are of production-ready quality (especially for WPF as you have to deal with air space issues)

Comment: Any WinForm browser component that you might have heard about?